# Hiding table data <td> using [ngStyle] Angular2

Tags: css, angular

I am trying to hide a table data using the following:

```
<td *ngFor="let tableHeaderItem of gridHeaderData" 
    [ngStyle]="{'hidden' : tableHeaderItem.hidden ? 'none' : 'table-cell'}">
```

but it isn't working. I tried removing the quotes `'hidden'` to `hidden` but it just doesn't work.

Comment: Why you go for ngStyle use ngHide instead of this. you have any problem with ngHide

Comment: Pretty sure it should be `[ngStyle]='{display: ...}'`; `hidden` is not a css attribute

Comment: Side note: my word, this syntax is ugly as all hell.... what made Angular decide to use a *more* convoluted template syntax?

Comment: making mistakes for rookie like me happens a lot with such confusing syntax..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have a `CSS` class named `hidden` that has `display: none` for this to work. Otherwise you could try the following:

```
<td *ngFor="let tableHeaderItem of gridHeaderData" 
    [ngStyle]="{'display' : tableHeaderItem.hidden ? 'none' : 'table-cell'}">
```

See the official **Angular2** documentation on the [`ngStyle`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgStyle-directive.html) directive for more details.

You could also use `[style.display]` like this:

```
<td *ngFor="let tableHeaderItem of gridHeaderData" 
    [style.display]="tableHeaderItem.hidden ? 'none' : 'table-cell'">
```

Answer (score 3):

what a mistake!... ur rite, alternately i made it working  by doing to following

```
[style.display]="tableHeaderItem.hidden ? 'none' : 'table-cell'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ngStyle` you can also use the `hidden` property:

```
<td *ngFor="let tableHeaderItem of gridHeaderData" 
    [hidden]="tableHeaderItem.hidden">
```

Comment: Using `[hidden]` is officially frowned upon by the **Angular2** team and is considered a "rookie mistake". http://angularjs.blogspot.be/2016/04/5-rookie-mistakes-to-avoid-with-angular.html

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. Without using `!important` it  doesn't seem to make a difference to the `ngStyle` examples in the other answers though. And with `ngStyle` you have to maintain the visible state (`table-cell`) while with hidden, this is done autmatically. If you are aware of the limitations it should still be fine.